# How can I fix the flicker occurring when selecting an NSCollectionViewItem?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, flicker, nscollectionview, nspopover

I've got an NSCollectionView which houses three columns of NSCollectionViewItems. In each of the NSCollectionViewItem prototype views, I have a single NSImageView. As far as I'm aware, this is a fairly standard setup. I think the problem stems from my use of a popover to present the collection view, but I'm honestly not sure. Basically, the problem I'm having is that when I click on one of the aforementioned NSCollectionViewItems to mark it as "selected," every once in awhile it flickers/flashes. It's not a total deal-breaker, but it's annoying enough to make me post this question.

Coming from the HTML/CSS/JS game, I started to think of all the ways I would prevent the flicker when building stuff with web technologies. My first thought was to make certain parts of the NSCollectionView (and subviews) layer-backed. I figured that by doing the drawing via layers or just setting the collection view to be layer-backed period, it would render better, kind of like GPU-enhanced animations in CSS (e.g. no sub-pixel antialiasing, enables z-depth, etc.).

So, I subclassed NSCollectionView and added a `[self setWantsLayer:YES]` in the
`-(id)initWithCoder:aDecoder` method. I was right! It removed the flickering altogether. Also, the scrolling became much smoother. However, in the process of making the flicker go away, everything else started messing up. The popover would take about 10s to load (vs. ~500ms originally), items would do weird overlapping things, etc.

My question to you all is this: what should I do? If anyone could help a brother out, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Any luck with this one? Facing the same problem

Comment: @Sunkas: Well, yes and no. I was awarded the [Tumbleweed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=558944) for this question because nobody left any advice or commented. However, I recently figured out what the problem was, so I'm glad you reminded me of this question. Give me a few minutes, and I'll explain in more detail what the problem was and how I went about fixing it. In short, the lag was created because I was connecting the image URL binding of each collection view item to the URL of a ridiculously large image rather than to a thumbnail. I'll post more shortly.

Comment: `[self setWantsLayer:YES]` did solve the flickering for me. Just had it in the wrong init method.